# Does Static class create an instance? msdn says i doesn't, but why constructor then?

Tags: c#, .net, static, singleton

I came across trying to understand the difference between singleton object and static class

and the simplest information I see everywhere is that static class DOES NOT create an instance while singleton requires to

But why the hell can I have the static constructor from static class? what does that mean? doesn't it create an instance?

if you run simple  code with breakpoint on static class constructor you will see it reaches it

I'm confused, anybody?

Comment: A non-static class can also have a static constructor. The main point is that it only runs once and you don't get to say when or how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But why that hell can I have the static constructor from static class? what does that mean? doesn't it create an instance?

No.  The static constructor allows you to initialize *static* members of the class (basically, the static state for that class).

With the singleton pattern, the static constructor (or a static inline initializer) often creates an instance, but that instance is still created via the normal, non-static constructor.  It's then stored within a static variable (the single "instance" variable).

Lazy-initialized singletons will avoid that, and initialize the static variable on demand.

A [static class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is a different thing - a static class will never work as a singleton, since you can't create an instance of a static class.  Static classes are specifically intended to be used when you will never create an instance.

A singleton will (typically) be created by having a non-static class, but using a private constructor (so the instance can only be created within that class).  There will be a static property used to retrieve a single instance of that class.  The class instance will either be created on demand or within the static constructor.

Comment: But this still leaves the question where static fields are stored.

Comment: @ThePoet - On the heap they need to be inside something. Like inside an instance.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That wasn't part of the question, as far as I could see...?

Comment: @ReedCopsey - No, it was my first interpretation of the title. But not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The static constructor is just a place where you can initialise your static member variables.  You don't need a static constructor - you can initialise the static member variables inline instead, but I think it's tidier to put them in the static constructor.

Remember that even though you don't instantiate the static class, you *do* instantiate its static members, and it's nice to have a place to do it.  This is an improvement on the way you have to do it in C++.

Note that your class doesn't need to be static in order to have a static constructor.  You can have a non-static class that provides both an ordinary constructor and a static constructor.  Same rule applies.